# How to find last hopping window using Apache Kafka Streams

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

I'm trying to get average value in the last 30 seconds using hopping windows. Here are windowing and suppressing code;

```
.windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofSeconds(30)).advanceBy(Duration.ofSeconds(30)).grace(Duration.ZERO))
 
.suppress(Suppressed.untilWindowCloses(Suppressed.BufferConfig.unbounded()))
```

When I do that, I'm getting hopping windows in 30 seconds. But I'm interested in just the last 30 seconds. Do I catch the last hopping windows? Then I'm going to look for the top 5 average value in that window using Java treeset.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the latest you can put the windows in a KTable and if they have the same key you will only have the latest window in the table.

Comment: All window keys are different to each other. How to put them using the same key?

Comment: You can use a map operation

Comment: I can't do that. Because there isn't any identity field on the windowed key. I'm getting window hash code which is changing each iteration.